# How to oppositely order two vectors in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the code below for oppositely ordering two vectors. It works, but I want to specify the line

```
B_diff(i) = B(i) - B(i+1);
```

to hold true not just for only 
`B_diff(i) = B(i) - B(i+1);` but for 
`B_diff(i) = B(i) - B(i+k);` where k can be any integer less than or equal to n. The same applies to "A". Any clues as to how I can achieve this in the program?

For example, I want to rearrange the first column of the matrix

```
A =

     1     4
     6     9
     3     8
     4     2
```

such that, the condition should hold true not only for

```
(a11-a12)(a21-a22)<=0;
```

but also for all

```
(a11-a13)(a21-a23)<=0;
(a11-a14)(a21-a24)<=0;
(a12-a13)(a22-a23)<=0;
(a12-a14)(a22-a24)<=0; and
(a13-a14)(a23-a24)<=0;
```

```
       ## MATLAB CODE ##
A = xlsread('column 1');
B = xlsread('column 2');

n = numel(A);

B_diff = zeros(n-1,1); %Vector to contain the differences between the elements of B
count_pos = 0; %To count the number of positive entries in B_diff
for i = 1:n-1
    B_diff(i) = B(i) - B(i+1);
    if B_diff(i) > 0
        count_pos = count_pos + 1;
    end
end

A_desc = sort(A,'descend'); %Sort the vector A in descending order

if count_pos > 0    %If B_diff contains positive entries, divide A_desc into two vectors
    A_less = A_desc(count_pos+1:n);
    A_great = sort(A_desc(1:count_pos),'ascend');
    A_new = zeros(n,1); %To contain the sorted elements of A
else
    A_new = A_desc; %This is then the sorted elements of A
end

if count_pos > 0
    A_new(1) = A_less(1);
    j = 2;  %To keep track of the index for A_less
    k = 1;  %To keep track of the index for A_great
    for i = 1:n-1
        if B_diff(i) <= 0
            A_new(i+1) = A_less(j);
            j = j + 1;
        else
            A_new(i+1) = A_great(k);
            k = k + 1;
        end
    end
end

A_diff = zeros(n-1,1);
for i = 1:n-1
    A_diff(i) = A_new(i) - A_new(i+1);
end

diff = [A_diff B_diff]
prod = A_diff.*B_diff
```

Comment: What must be the expected output for the given sample input data?

Comment: It should be something like this                                                                        A =

     3     4
     1     9
     4     8
     6     2                                                                                                                 where the first column is shuffled while the second remains the same

Comment: If I assume: `a11` as `col-1,row-1` of A,  `a12` as `col-1,row-2` of A,  `a21` as `col-2,row-1` of A, ... `a24` as `col-2,row-4` of A, where A is the two-column input data, I don't see how the expected output, `A = [3 4; 1 9; 4 8 ;6 2]` satisfies the second condition of `(a11-a13)(a21-a23)<=0;`

Answer (score 0):

The following code orders the first column of A opposite to the order of the second column.

```
A= [1 4; 6 9; 3 8; 4 2];       % sample matrix
[~,ix]=sort(A(:,2));           % ix is the sorting permutation of A(:,2)
inverse=zeros(size(ix));
inverse(ix) = numel(ix):-1:1;  % the un-sorting permutation, reversed  
B = sort(A(:,1));              % sort the first column
A(:,1)=B(inverse);             % permute the first column according to inverse
```

Result:

```
A =

     4     4
     1     9
     3     8
     6     2
```